# Titanium Studio Webview not letting me interact with website

Tags: ios, webview, titanium

Part of an app I am working on needs to access an external website to answer a few questions.

When that is needed, I am opening a web view and the URL set to this site. The page loads fine, but there is no way to interact. The textfields cannot be edited and the buttons cannot be clicked. To make sure it was not my website (works from iOS safari fine) I pointed the web view to www.google.com and cannot click the search button there either. Basically:

```
var webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url: 'http://www.google.com'});
win.add(webView);
win.open();
```

Is there some trick to being able to interact with the website through a web view? At this time I cannot use a native app and web service and need to get the app working with the existing website to fill out this form.

Titanium Studio 2.1.2 and iOS6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe are you putting some View (Ti.UI.View) after putting the WebView in the Window?

Comment: Ha, thanks. Been looking at this so long I just couldn't see it anymore. Had an empty TabView loading after the web view