# Titanium SDK webview component doesnt allow interaction with website it loads

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-widgets

I am trying to implement a side panel using Titanium wherein I have couple of options under the side panel menu and each menu option loads a different view. One of the options loads a webview. The website or html loads perfectly in the webview component but I am not able to interact with it; in the sense that I am not able to click on the links or do anything as such. This happens both with local as well as remote html.

For the side panel, I am integrating the drawer widget provided by Ricardo Alcocer, link to his github project is - https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/alloy-widget-drawermenu

Here goes the code blocks.

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" id="win">
        <Require type="widget" src="com.alcoapps.drawermenu" id="drawermenu"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

mainview.xml (Side menu option to load the webview)

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="mainView">
        <View id="mainTopBar">
            <View id="menuButton"/>
        </View>
        <WebView id="chartView" url="http://www.google.co.in"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

menuview.xml (Side Panel)

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="menuView">
        <View id="menuTopBar"/>
        <TableView class="menuTable" id="menuTable">
            <TableViewRow class="tableRow" id="row1">
                <View id="rowContainer">
                    <View id="rowSkull" class="rowIcon"/><Label id="rowLabel" class="rowLabel">MainView</Label>
                </View>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="tableRow" id="row2">
                <View id="rowContainer">
                    <View id="rowGear" class="rowIcon"/><Label id="rowLabel" class="rowLabel">Settings</Label>
                </View>
            </TableViewRow>
        </TableView>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

index.js

```
var controls=require('controls');

// get main and menu view as objects
var menuView=controls.getMenuView();
var mainView=controls.getMainView();

// attach event listener to menu button
mainView.menuButton.add(controls.getMenuButton({
    h: '60',
    w: '60'
}));

//Minor changes to click event. Update the menuOpen status;
mainView.menuButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    $.drawermenu.showhidemenu();
    $.drawermenu.menuOpen=!$.drawermenu.menuOpen;
}); // method is exposed by widget


// get config view as objects
var configView=controls.getConfigView();

//add menu view to ConfigView exposed by widget
configView.menuButton.add(controls.getMenuButton({
                h: '60',
                w: '60'
            }));

//Minor changes to click event. Update the menuOpen status;
configView.menuButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    $.drawermenu.showhidemenu();
    $.drawermenu.menuOpen=!$.drawermenu.menuOpen;
}); // method is exposed by widget

$.drawermenu.init({
    menuview:menuView.getView(),
    mainview:mainView.getView(),
    duration:200,
    parent: $.index
});

//variable to controler de open/close slide
var activeView = 1;

// add event listener in this context
menuView.menuTable.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    $.drawermenu.showhidemenu();
    $.drawermenu.menuOpen = false; //update menuOpen status to prevent inconsistency.
    if(e.rowData.id==="row1"){
        if(activeView!=1){
            $.drawermenu.drawermainview.remove(configView.getView());
            activeView = 1;
        } else {
            activeView = 1;
        }
    } 
    if(e.rowData.id==="row2"){
        if(activeView!=2){
            $.drawermenu.drawermainview.add(configView.getView());
            activeView = 2;
        } else{
            activeView = 2;
        }
    }
    // on Android the event is received by the label, so watch out!
    Ti.API.info(e.rowData.id); 
});

$.index.open();
```

controls.js

```
var Alloy=require('alloy');

exports.getMainView=function(){
    return Alloy.createController('mainview');;
};

exports.getMenuView=function(){
    return Alloy.createController('menuview');  
};

exports.getMenuButton=function(args){
    var v=Ti.UI.createView({
        height: args.h,
        width: args.w,
        backgroundColor: '#A1D0E0'
    });

    var b=Ti.UI.createView({
        height: "20dp",
        width: "20dp",
        backgroundImage: "/106-sliders.png"
    });

    v.add(b);

    return v;
};

//Get the Configuration Controller
exports.getConfigView=function(){
    return Alloy.createController('config');
};
```

I haven't provided the code blocks for Settings page (the second side panel menu option) as well as the style sheets which I think should not be causing the problem.

I had a look at [Titanium Studio Webview not letting me interact with website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847453/titanium-studio-webview-not-letting-me-interact-with-website)
but it doesn't help in my case. I need to have this kind of implementation and I think there certainly should be some workaround.

Any kind of help will be highly apppreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Guys. I have got an answer to my own question. I just needed to set the 'willHandleTouches' property of my webview to false in my tss file. Did not know this was so simple after all. :)

Comment: I was facing the same problem and your answer had helped me a lot! Thanks for sharing it =)

Comment: Great to hear it helped you. @CarlosHenriqueLustosa